# Improving While-Loop with Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, while-loop

I have given the following three variables:

```
start      = 30    #starting value
end        = 60    #ending value
slice_size = 6     #value difference per tuble
```

`start` and `end` are row numbers of an array. My goal is to create an array/list of tuples, where each tuples includes as much items as `slice_size` defines. A little example: If `start` and `end` have the above values the first four tuples would be:

[[30,35],[36,41],[42,47],[48,53],...].

But now comes the clue: the first value of the next tuple does not start with the first value before + `slice_size`, but rather with first value + `slice_size/2`. So I want something like this:

[[30,35],[33,38],[36,41],[39,44],...].

This list of tuples goes on until `end` is reached or right before it is reached - so until `<=end` . The last value of the list is not allowed to pass the value of `end`. The value of `slice_size` must of course always be an even number to work properly.

My nooby attempt is done by a while loop:

```
condition = 0
i = 0
list = []
half_slice = int(slice_size /2)
while condition <= end:
    list.append([start+int(slice_size/2)*i,start+((slice_size-1)+i*half_slice)])
    condition = start+((slice_size-1)+i*int(slice_size/2))
    i += 1
```

The thing is, it works. However I know this is complete rubbish and I want to improve my skill. Do you have a suggestion how to do it in a couple of code lines?

Comment: So with your code is `[57, 62]` a valid output or no because the last value is over `60`?

Comment: This would not be a valid output. If `end=62` then it would be.

Comment: KK just checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must not use `list` as it is a reserved word

```
import numpy as np

start      = 30    #starting value
end        = 60    #ending value
slice_size = 6     #value difference per tuble

l = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(np.arange(start, end, slice_size/2),
                          np.arange(start + slice_size - 1,
                                    end + slice_size - 1,
                                    slice_size/2)
                          )
     ]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[30.0, 35.0],
 [33.0, 38.0],
 [36.0, 41.0],
 [39.0, 44.0],
 [42.0, 47.0],
 [45.0, 50.0],
 [48.0, 53.0],
 [51.0, 56.0],
 [54.0, 59.0],
 [57.0, 62.0]]
```

Comment: You should add a space after your commas and before and after operators.

Comment: Per the most recent comment in the question `[57.0, 62.0]` should not be in the result (though the OP's code does include it). :)

Comment: right. I could copy your definition of end for the range command. Or I could leave it. OP should get idea anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Do NOT use `list` as a variable name. It is a reserved key-word.
2) Not a NumPy solution but you can use list comprehension:

```
start      = 30    #starting value
end        = 60    #ending value
slice_size = 6     #value difference per tuble

result = [[current, current + slice_size - 1] for current in range(start, end - slice_size + 2, slice_size // 2)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[30, 35], [33, 38], [36, 41], [39, 44], [42, 47], [45, 50], [48, 53], [51, 56], [54, 59]]
```

This will work for an odd number `slice_size` as well.

Comment: Thank you! A oneliner - I love it. However it does not include the last value if `end` is on point. So if `end=62` your solution does not include the tuple `[57,62]`.

Comment: My bad, its because the range end is non inclusive. It needs to be `+ 2`.